# Why cant I work with downloaded bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded the *Compiled CSS and JS* version of bootstrap from this [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v4.3.1/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist.zip). unzipped it inside my project root directory and referenced them inside my html file. My html file is now like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Todo Maker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
</body>

<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Now if I run the page then it doesn't show the bootstrap navbar properly. Its showing like this 
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuVsh.png)

But If i use cdn for bootstrap css and js then it works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

===== edit========

After some digging around I can see that I cant find the bootstrap styles in the bootstrap.min.css or in bootstrap.css files that I downloaded. For example I cant find any style for class  *.navbar-inverse*.

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: are you running this form localhost?

Comment: @j08691 console is empty. nothing showing in console

Comment: @Barbu Barbu yes running from localhost . tried both in chrome and IE

Comment: First guess would be it's just a simple file path issue. Since currently if your URL was say www.example.com/folder/something then your current link href to your files would expect to find your bootstrap directory inside /folder/something/ directory. Are you just missing the first slash to refer to your WWW Root? Eg; `href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"` vs `href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Comment: @DancyHeart: The console is only one debugging tool at your disposal.  Also check the network tab in the browser's debugging tools.  Is the stylesheet loaded as expected?  Does the server's response contain the styling you expect?  When you inspect the element(s) on your page, what styles are applied?

Comment: @Chris W. if I use the slash before the path then it doesn't work and shows error in console. Also the way I am using the path its correct as I can pen the files from browser's console

Comment: @David I have edited my questions. After listening to you I investigated the css style on console and found out that some classes in bootstrap.min.css is missing. Why is that?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 doesn't have a `navbar-inverse` class. That's BS3. Your example code looks fine when I run it under BS3, but incorrect, and like your image when I run it with BS4. Are you mixing versions?

Comment: @ j08691 thanks. I guess thats what happened. In the cdn its versions 3.4.1 and I downloaded version 4.3.1. Can you please post the answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 doesn't have a `navbar-inverse` class. That's BS3. Your example code looks fine when I run it under BS3, but incorrect, and like your image when I run it with BS4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `.navbar-expand` or `.navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}` classname in your `<nav>` element to make the bootstrap style work.

Then you'll also need to add the proper classnames for the navlinks like so:

```
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 1</a>
      </li>
```

You can read more here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: But the OP says if they link to a CDN it works fine without having to change their code

Comment: he's probably linking to an older version